# Spring Batch Restart - Not picking up correct row

Tags: spring, spring-batch, restart

I have a spring batch job that has the following attributes:

```
    commit-interval: 25.
    skip-limit of 3.
```

In my integration tests, I have injected in a fake writer that will throw the skippable exception, and this in turn is injected with a list of ids, which will cause the exception to be thrown.

In the before of my test I create 135 rows. I configure that rows

```
    "9", "11", "44", "51", "70"
```

will all be the rows that cause the ItemWriter to throw the exception.

All works well on the first run, and as expected, the job fails after the 3 commits of 50, on row 51, or rather when "something" in the writer has detected a skippable exception that has now exceeded the limit of 3. Also, I have asserted that 9, 11 and 44 are registered in the skippable listener which I would expect.

I realise that the batch job has not individually wrapped the items in transactions before it fails, like id did for 9, 11 and 44 because it already knows that the skip limit is reached.

However, when I restart the job, the starting row is 74 - Not 51 as I would expect.

Therefore from 51 to 73 are skipped?

I cannot figure this one out. Or why it would skip the chunk that has failed completely.

Any help would be appreciated.

David.

Answer (score 0):

The fix to this bug will be included in the next release of spring batch.

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/BATCH-2122